# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable; range function

Tags: tuples, range, typeerror

```
x = range(0, 10, 1)
print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[29], line 1
    x = range(0, 10, 1)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I don´t sleep for over 24h and now I think I´m losing my mind.
Can someone please tell me what could be wrong here...

I want to do this:

```
x_3741 = np.array(range(0, len(pim_3741), 1))
```

And it was working hours ago. Now I can´t even get the range function to work...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide sufficient details in the question to answer with certainty, but I suspect that you have assigned to `range` earlier in the code, replacing the builtin function definition with a tuple value.

Search for:

```
range = (1,2,3)
```

Or the like.

Comment: I was coming here right now to say it´s fixed. I restarted python without saving and now it works again, so I think you were most probably right. I´d give you an upvote but I believe I don´t have enough 'reputation' yet ahah Thank you! And sorry for the lack of info.